# AWS DMS - Migrate - only schema

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-dms

We have noticed that if a table is empty in SQL Server, the empty table does not come via DMS. Only after inserting a record it starts to show up.

Just checking, is there a way to get the schema only from DMS?

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked into [AWS Schema Conversion Tool](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/SchemaConversionTool/latest/userguide/CHAP_Welcome.html)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Schema conversion tool](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/SchemaConversionTool/latest/userguide/CHAP_Welcome.html) for moving DB objects and Schema. Its a free tool by AWS and can be installed on On-Prem server or on EC2. It gives a good report before you can actually migrate the DB schema and other DB objects. It shows how many Tables, SP's Funcs etc can be directly migrated and shows possible solutions too.